# Showing well defined and onto for a function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Problem: Define $\mathbb{Z}_{mn} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ by $f([x]_{mn})=([x]_m,[x]_n).$ Show that $f$ is a function and $f$ is onto iff $gcd(m,n)=1$

$(=>)$
Suppose $f$ is onto and is a function. Show that $gcd(m,n)=1$. It follows there exists a $[x]\in{Z}_{mn}$ such that $f([x]_{mn})=([x]_m,[x]_n)$. Since $f$ is well defined there exists a unique solution to $x\equiv a\pmod{m}$ and $x\equiv b\pmod{n}$ Thus gcd(m,n)=1. But i still don't know how to show it though?

$(<=)$
Suppose the $gcd(m,n)=1$. We first show that $f$ is well defined. Suppose $[x]_{mn}=[y]_{mn}$. Then $f([x]_{mn})=([x]_m,[x]_n)$ and  $f([y]_{mn})=([y]_m,[y]_n)$. We want to show that $[x]_m=[y]_m$ and $[x]_n=[y]_n$. Since $[x]_{mn}=[y]_{mn}\implies x\equiv y \pmod{mn}\implies mnz=x-y$ for some $z\in Z$. Thus $[x]_m=[mnz+y]_m=[y]_m$ and $[x]_n=[mnz+y]_n=[y]_n$. Thus $f$ is well defined. Now we show $f$ is onto. That is show there is a solution to $x\equiv a \pmod{m}$ and $x\equiv b\pmod{n}$ Since the $gcd(m,n)=1$ there does exists a unique solution to this system by the CRT. Thus there exists a unique $[x]\in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ such that $f([x]_{mn})=([x]_m,[x]_n)$

I think my reverse direction looks ok but im not sure about my forward direction.

Comment: For $(\Rightarrow)$, if $gcd(m,n)\neq 1$, what is the order of $[1]_{mn}$? So what can you say about the order of the image of $f$?

Comment: Well if the $gcd(m,n)>1$ then we have $x\equiv a\pmod{m}$ and $x\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and since d=gcd(m,n)>1 then there exist either no solutions or more then one solution since there would be $d|a$ solutions modulo mn. If that is the case then $f$ would not be well defined.